# Iterate JSON object string

Tags: javascript, json

I am a javascript noob. I have a JSON string created by google gson API after creating the json string which I am passing it to my javascript function. So in a javascript variable I have a string as follows

```
'{"validationCode":"V10291","caseNumber":"2010CF101011","documentSource":"EFILE","countyDocumentID":"CD102","documentTitle":"D Title","signedDate":"01/01/2012","signedBy":"CPSJC","comments":"YES Comments"}'
```

How to iterate over this or get a value of the key something like I have to find validationCode or caseNumber, but this is String? Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get it into a native JavaScript object with `JSON.parse`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourJSONString);
```

Then you can iterate the keys with a standard for in loop

```
for(var k in obj)
    if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k))
        console.log(k, " = ", obj[k]);
```

Or access particular keys like `validationCode` or `caseNumber` directly:

```
var caseNum = obj.caseNumber;
var validationCode = obj.validationCode;
```

---

Note that really old browsers don't support `JSON.parse`, so if you want to support them, you can either use Papa Crockford's [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), or jQuery, which has a [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) utility method.

Comment: Thank you this worked as it was json String. The other answers did not since I did not have Json object

Comment: Does really old javascript include IE 6? :)

Comment: @SandeepNair - yes.  Even IE7 is lacking support or the JSON object.  Sorry :(  If you need to support them I'd recommend using either jQuery or crockford's json2 (both linked above) to do your parsing

Comment: Adam, why do you use `{}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)` instead of `obj.hasOwnProperty(k)`? Also the `hasOwnProperty` check is only needed if you are working with code that extends `Object.prototype`, I refuse to use any code that does that and add that bloat to every single loop that iterates properties.

Comment: @JuanMendes - just one of those better safe than sorry things.  I don't know what OP might be using in the background that might be messing with `Object.prototype`, so I thought I'd throw it in there.  Also, `{}.hashOwnProperty.call` instead of `obj.hasOwnProperty` is just an extra extra safe thing I picked up on [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/) (though definitely not needed here -- just habit I put myself in)

Comment: @AdamRackis My problem with those is that you add a lot of bloat to the code. Heck, I could think of a million things to make my code safer, but I'm not going to do it everywhere (type checking, property checking) For libraries that don't know what they're going to go against, those may be necessary, but for code that I control, I prefer to set standards instead of adding defensive coding everywhere. Definitely a personal choice

Comment: The reason for using `{}.hasOwnProperty` is to prevent against the possibility of your object having overwritten the `hasOwnProperty` property, I don't think that's good practice, if someone overwrites hasOwnProperty, they have bigger problems to deal with.

Comment: @Juan - I tend to agree.  I *don't* litter my own code with stuff like that.  But when writing code for folks on SO I prefer to keep it safer, since I can't be sure what else is going on in the background (who knows what messy libraries they have).  And yeah - overwriting `hasOwnProperty` is a terrible idea.  That most certainly isn't necessary here, just a habit I put myself in for the one time in a million where I might need it -  since this doesn't really add code bloat imo

Comment: @AdamRackis I tend to think those take away from the real point of the question since those are personal choices. Thanks for a good discussion

Answer (score 1):

You could do a `for ... in` to loop through the object properties:

```
var person={fname:"John",lname:"Doe",age:25};

var x;

for (x in person)
{
   document.write(person[x] + " ");
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery framework you can use : `jQuery.parseJSON`

If not you can use `JSON.parse()` or you can use `eval` (which is less safe).