# load JSON to HTML Table

Tags: jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterate JSON object string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316453/iterate-json-object-string)

i try to make a simple table from JSON. pls dont advice to use any plugin.
I need advice whats the simple way to loop keys below without define the item.keys one by one?

```
    $.getJSON('JSON_URL', function(data) {
    var table='';
    $.each( data, function(index,item){
    for (var x=0;x < item.length;x++)
        {table+='<tr><td>'+item[x].app_id+'</td><td>'+item[x].app_desc+'</td><td>'+item[x].cby+'</td><td>'+item[x].con+'</td><td>'+item[x].uby+'</td><td>'+item[x].uon+'</td></tr>';}
    });
    table+='';
    $("#users tbody").html( table );        
    });
```

my JSON

```
 {"vntret": [{"app_id":"APP0OKSD","app_desc":"Application 1","cby":"amolerc.com","con":"2013-01-18 22:39:33","uby":null,"uon":null},{"app_id":"APP0BWNS","app_desc":"kjkljlkjkl","cby":"padusi.com","con":"2013-01-19 00:53:03","uby":null,"uon":null}]}
```

Thanks

Comment: there are 100's of posts on how to do this....What Have You Tried??

Comment: To iterate over object properties, use `for...in`. However I would advice against doing this in your case, because the order in which the properties are iterated over is likely to differ in different browsers. I.e. the columns would show up in different order in different browsers.

Comment: codes above works, i asked how to populate the keys value onto the table without define the item.key(s) --- i did search and try some codes in other thread but doesnt works.

Comment: What does your code do wrong? We also need to see the HTML we see in the jQuery selector, at least.

Comment: @FelixKling He could get the keys first into an array, sort them, then use the list to pull them out. Then they would always fall in the same order. What do you think?

Comment: @Lee: Yes, if they are easily sortable... but if he wants a custom sort order than it seems to be too much hassle to go through. I mean, take `app_id` and `app_desc` for example, or `uoy` and `uon`... they are not in natural order. I just think there is not much to gain through that.

Comment: @LeeMeador thanks, thats what i meant. so i can use it as generic function. an example pls?

Comment: @Lee: However, he could use a predefined array of keys and iterate through them...

Comment: Hi Guys Thank You for your advice, 
the solution is [for ... in] as your advise

Comment: @akauts: Well, I actually recommended *against* it, since you will get different results in different browsers. You cannot control the order of the columns. But if this is not a requirement for you, that's of course the solution.